# AbortBroadcast not working for MMS

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, mms, abortbroadcast

I am trying to abort a particulat text if it is an MMS and is originating from a particular number. I have used abortBroadcast(). I am successful in detecting if it is an MMS or not but after that abortBroadcast does not work. Also can someone please explain how abortBroadcast works.

Here is  my CODE:

```
 if(incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("*MYNUMBER**")){
                        try {

                            abortBroadcast();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Is this on KitKat? If not, are you sure `incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("*MYNUMBER**")` is true? If so, what priority is your receiver set to?

Comment: Yes incomingNumber.equalsIgnoreCase("*MYNUMBER**") is true and the priority is set to 1000. No it is Jelly Bean

Comment: Do you have another app installed that receives SMS/MMS?

Comment: Yes I have google hangout that reads the sms

Comment: I believe that's your problem. AFAIK, the actual maximum for a Receiver's priority is 999. Yours at 1000 should correctly set it to the max, so that's good. However, IIRC, Google Hangouts actually sets its own priority to something crazy like `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and somehow "hijacks" the priority chain. If you were to uninstall Hangouts, I believe your code would work as expected. If you can't or don't want to, I think you're kinda stuck.

Comment: Hi. I turned off Google Hangout. It still does not work.

Comment: Are you sure your code is reaching the `abortBroadcast()` statement? Also, how do you know `abortBroadcast()` isn't working?

Comment: Yes. It reaches the method. Even after triggering abortBroadcast(), I receive the MMS. I just found out that abortBroadcast() works only for  android 1.6 and that too only for SMS. Can you suggest something only for MMS and for higher versions of android OS.

Comment: The default messaging app receives the MMS

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like that

```
incomingnumber.contains("yournumber")
      try{

       abortbroadcast()

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can abort broadcast for mms prior to kitkat, but kitkat does not allow you to abort broadcast unless you are default app,
 add android:priority="999" in your receiver' intent-filter tag like

```
    <receiver android:name=".MmsListener" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
      <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED" />

            <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.wap.mms-message" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

this should work